# Overlapping labels on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlapping

I have used a csv file to generate a bar graph using ggplot in R. But the labels on x-axis are overlapping with each other.
below is the code :

```
library(ggplot2)

options(repr.plot.width = 100)

ggplot(data,aes(State,Confirmed))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
```

Please help me to solve this overlapping issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function is theme().

Here is an example:

```
# data
data <- data.frame(
  name = c("hey! sample very long text 1", "hey! sample very long text 2", 
         "hey! sample very long text 3", "hey! sample very long text 4", 
         "hey! sample very long text 5", "hey! sample very long text 6",
         "hey! sample very long text 7", "hey! sample very long text 8",
         "hey! sample very long text 9", "hey! sample very long text 10"),  
  value = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 40)
)

# barplot
ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5, hjust = 1))

# or
ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```